# What is the javascript text editor used at Quora?

Tags: html, rich-text-editor

I like this inline text editor used at Quora:

[image: Quora Rich Text Editor]
http://www.quora.com/Brogramming/How-does-a-programmer-become-a-brogrammer

However, I was unable to identify this one. Does anybody recognize this editor?

Comment: why don't you ask this on Quora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://www.quora.com/Quora-Rich-Text-Editor?q=quora+text+editor](http://www.quora.com/Quora-Rich-Text-Editor?q=quora%20text%20editor)

Answer (score 1):

You could pull off something like that using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)  It's very flexible and does wonderful code highlighting.  I've implemented it as a template editor built into a CMS I work on.  It was even pretty easy getting it to handle some of the special syntax specific to our CMS.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely proprietary.

Perhaps TinyMCE would be a better solution for you?